# Return just last day from all available rows for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Ok, This has me stumped...

My first query below returns all possible rows I am interested in just fine.

**First Query**:

```
select * from FloatTable where Val > 0 and TagIndex = 325
```

My second query below which is supposed to return me all the rows with last day (doesn't necessary calendar last day but whatever max value is present in database) of each month from all available rows. BUT I get all months except month of May (integer value of 5).

**Second Query**

```
select 
DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
from FloatTable 
WHERE 
  (TagIndex = 325) AND 
  (Val > 0) AND 
  DateAndTime IN (Select Max(DateAndTime) from FloatTable 
                  group by month(DateAndTime), Year(DateAndTime)
                 )
```

Using SQL-Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      select  DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(DateAndTime) ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC) RN 
      FROM FloatTable 
      WHERE TagIndex = 325 
        AND Val > 0
     )A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can make use of the new window functions like `LAST_VALUE()`
`FIRST_VALUE()`.

**Using FIRST_VALUE()**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
    ,FIRST_VALUE(DateAndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(DateAndTime) 
                                           ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC) Last_Date 
    FROM FloatTable 
    WHERE TagIndex = 325 
    AND Val > 0
    ) A
WHERE DateAndTime = Last_Date
```

**Using LAST_VALUE()**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
    ,LAST_VALUE(DateAndTime) OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(DateAndTime) ORDER BY DateAndTime 
              ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Last_Date 
    FROM FloatTable 
    WHERE TagIndex = 325 
    AND Val > 0
    ) A
WHERE DateAndTime = Last_Date
```

Comment: Ok, first suggestions worked. Last_Value() still repeats values. Any ideas on what's making month of 'May' not show in my second query? Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry I over looked something, have a look now for second option.

Comment: Seconds method still retrieves values other than the last available days.. First method works great! Thank you so much.. Still doesn't make sense why my second query works for all months but month of May.

Answer (score 1):

Your second query does not work (as you expect) because you put the conditions only in the main query and not in the subquery. If you add them, it will work fine:

```
SELECT  
  DateAndTime, TagIndex, Val
FROM FloatTable 
WHERE 
  TagIndex = 325 AND 
  Val > 0 AND 
  DateAndTime IN 
    ( SELECT Max(DateAndTime) FROM FloatTable 
      WHERE TagIndex = 325 AND 
            Val > 0 
      GROUP BY Month(DateAndTime), Year(DateAndTime)
    ) ;
```

Using a Common Table Expression, it may be more readable:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT  
      DateAndTime, TagIndex, Val
    FROM FloatTable 
    WHERE 
      TagIndex = 325 AND 
      Val > 0
  )
SELECT  
  DateAndTime, TagIndex, Val
FROM cte 
WHERE DateAndTime IN 
        ( SELECT Max(DateAndTime) FROM cte 
          GROUP BY Month(DateAndTime), Year(DateAndTime)
        ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Since you need to return *just the last day from all records*

```
select 
DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
from FloatTable 
WHERE 
(TagIndex = 325) AND 
(Val > 0) AND 
DateAndTime=(select top 1 from FloatTable order by DateAndTime desc)
```

Or Try using [EOMONTH()](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=49ffa5c2-03a3-4888-aac2-a80320f2faf4&tkw=last-day-of-the-month-function) function

if you have last date of every month in *your FloatTable*
like this

```
select 
    DateAndTime, TagIndex,Val
    from FloatTable 
    WHERE 
    (TagIndex = 325) AND 
    (Val > 0) AND 
    DateAndTime=EOMONTH(DateAndTime)
```

Comment: `EOMONTH()` returns the last calender day of a month.